# Bug Fixing in moving an object and setting new coordinates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, core-animation

I have a very simple issue, but I am not able to find the reason for this bug. Any ideas appreciated.

So, I have an object of `UIImageView` and flick it (move it) from Point A(x1,y1) to Point B(x2, y2) to Point C(x2,y2), and so on....

When I move it from A to B to C to D and so on... ***WITHOUT ANIMATION, it works !***

When I move it from A to B to C .... and so on... ***WITH ANIMATION -> There is a bug !*** *Only A to B works, B to C,... and so forth appears some place else.*

I basically implement the `touchesBegan` method, and `touchesEnd` method and move the object to the new location with

```
//NO ANIMATION  ==> Works !

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"End of touch");

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    object.center = CGPointMake(location.x,  location.y); 

}
```

..

```
//ADDING ANIMATION ==> Bug ! 

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"End of touch");

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    [self spinLayer:object.layer duration:1 direction:SPIN_CLOCK_WISE newFrame:location];
    tempFrame = location;   // tempFrame is global. 
}
```

And at the end of animation, I do

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {

object.center = tempFrame;

// I assign this because the object has to be updated to its new location to move it to points B, C, D and so forth...

// The object is actually at the desired point. But it appears on the SCREEN at a different location although it `NSLogs` at the right point.

}
```

---

**This is the bug :**

When I assign `object.center = tempFrame;`  I expect the object to be at (x2,y2). It is technically at (x2,y2) (when I `NSlog` the location, I found out), but it appears elsewhere on the screen.

If I again move it to Point C, it uses (x2, y2) and correctly moves to (x3,y3), but it appears somewhere else on the screen again !

Any ideas ??????

Comment: Can we see the method `spinLayer:duration:direction:newFrame:`?

Comment: Sure. Its just simple animation... http://pastebin.com/P0ypj7RY

Comment: why don't you animate keypath `position.x` and `postion.y` instead of `transform.translate.X/Y`? I checked the animation on position and works  quite fine

Comment: @MichałZygar Just add that as the answer to this question :) I will accept it. I don't want to delete this question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using animatio `transform.translation.x` and `transform.translation.y` key paths I'd suggest using `position.x` and `position.y` keypaths. 
So, change the fragment

```
theAnimationX=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
theAnimationX.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(newFrame.x-object.center.x)];
theAnimationY=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
theAnimationY.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(newFrame.y-object.center.y)];
```

to

```
theAnimationX=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
theAnimationX.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newFrame.x)];
theAnimationY=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
theAnimationY.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(newFrame.y)];
```

You can also use just `position` keypath in this case (and set CGPoint as `toValue`)

Comment: AWESOME !  Any way you can help me out with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668731/moving-rotating-an-object-using-its-updated-position-and-tilt ???? It's a follow up, but a different question from this :)